# Scala - Pattern matching - Is it possible to detect if value is a case class?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I use pattern matching to discover type of my propertie, like that:

```
value match {
    case s: String => processString(s)
    case l: Long => processLong(l)
    case c1: myCaseClass1 => processCaseClass(c1)
    case c2: myCaseClass2 => processCaseClass(c2)
    case c3: myCaseClass3 => processCaseClass(c3)
    case _ => nothingToDo
}
```

Is it possible to detect if value is a case class without enumerate all my case classes?

Comment: You seem to be asking a wrong question ... What could possibly be the reason to want to do this? What are you _really_ trying to do here? How is `processCaseClass` defined?

Comment: I love questions with an answer explaining how to do it and another answer explaining why it can't be done, especially when they're both upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Every case class and tuple extends `Product` trait by default. So you can catch case classes and tuples by using Product. Warning: this might consider a normal class as case class in case normal extends `Product` trait.

```
value match {
  case _: Product => //catches all the case class values with tuple values also.
}
```

If you want to catch only case classes then

```
value match {
  case x: Product if !x.getClass.getName.startsWith("scala.Tuple") =>
    //catches all the case classes.
}
```

#### Scala REPL

```
scala> case class Dog(name: String)
defined class Dog

scala> case class Cat()
defined class Cat

scala> val value = Dog("foo")
value: Dog = Dog(foo)

scala> value match { case _: Product => println("caught") }
caught

scala> val value = Cat()
value: Cat = Cat()

scala> value match { case _: Product => println("caught") }
caught
```

Comment: This will also catch all tuples, which aren't case classes per say.

Comment: This will incorrectly identify the following class as a case class: `class Foo(i: Int) extends Product1[Int] { override def _1 = i; override def canEqual(that: Any) = true }`

Answer (score 2):

No, this is impossible. Case classes simply contain some compiler-generated members and have a compiler-generated companion object, which however you could implement manually anyway. It is impossible to distinguish between a case class and a non-case class implementing the same members. [The Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes) even includes the exact expansion of the compiler generated members.

You could write a class manually that behaves *exactly* like a case class and there is no way of distinguishing them.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a generic context you can use a `TypeTag` to get more information about the type of the value that gets passed in:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, symbolOf}

def foo[T: TypeTag](foo: T) =
  if (symbolOf[T].isClass && symbolOf[T].asClass.isCaseClass)
    println("It's a case class!")
  else
    println("Nope :(")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> case class Foo(a: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> foo(Foo(3))
It's a case class!

scala> foo("bar")
Nope :(
```